# code to print out list of list data as a linux diff command

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python codes. I have a list of list that has ordered line that acts as a linux diff command. The list of list is structured as [[operation,linenum in 1st file, linenum in 2nd file]], [['c',4,5]] and the print out will be 4c5. Now if we have multiple instances of the same operation consecutively it will print out in one command line. For example [['c',4,5],['c',6,7],['c',7,8],['d',9,10]] this will print out 4,6,7c5,7,8 and 9d10.
Below is code that I tried and its giving me output:

```
Output:
{1, 2} {'d'} {0} #I'm using set() to get me the common items.
5c4 
{7} {'a'} {8, 7} #<-Set() is filping the position of the numbers here.  
{10, 13} {'d'} {10, 12}
#the last 2 'C' are not showing up.
```

What is going wrong with this code and what would be a better way to do it?
Thanks in advance.

```
dist=[['d', 1, 0], ['d', 2, 0], ['c', 5, 4], ['a', 7, 7], ['a', 7, 8], ['d', 10, 10], ['d', 13, 12], ['c', 14, 13], ['c', 15, 14]]
op=[]
line1=[]
line2=[]
for rows in range(len(dist)):
    if (rows==0 and dist[rows][0]==dist[rows+1][0])or(dist[rows][0]==dist[rows-1][0]) :
        op.append(dist[rows][0])
        line1.append(dist[rows][1])
        line2.append(dist[rows][2])
        if dist[rows][0]!=dist[rows+1][0]:
            print(set(line1),set(op),set(line2))
            op.clear()
            line1.clear()
            line2.clear()
    elif dist[rows][0]==dist[rows+1][0]:
        op.append(dist[rows][0])
        line1.append(dist[rows][1])
        line2.append(dist[rows][2])
        if dist[rows][0]!=dist[rows+1][0]:
            print(set(line1),set(op),set(line2))
            op.clear()
            line1.clear()
            line2.clear()
    else:
        print(f'{dist[rows][1]}{dist[rows][0]}{dist[rows][2]}')
```

Comment: You only print if the command character changes.  For the very last item, there is no following command to change.  You need to repeat your processing AFTER the loop to catch any pending items that have not been printed, meaning `op` is not empty.

Comment: Thanks for that, I just added a dummy ['d', 0,0] at the end and it printed out the last 2 'c' sublists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach that is using `groupby` from the standard library module `itertools`:

```py
from itertools import groupby

for op, group in groupby(dist, key=lambda item: item[0]):
    left, right = zip(*(item[1:] for item in group))
    cmd = (
        ",".join(str(n) for n in sorted(set(left)))
        + op
        + ",".join(str(n) for n in sorted(set(right)))
    )
    print(cmd)
```

Result for your sample (without the added dummy item):

```
1,2d0
5c4
7a7,8
10,13d10,12
14,15c13,14
```

I'm not sure if sorting the line numbers is correct, though: you should specify the requirement if that's not the case, i.e. outline what exactly has to happen.

Comment: Thanks for that, I made up the line numbers so some of them are not correct. I was mostly looking for the formatting.